# Why do some architectures don't have MOV?

Tags: assembly, architecture, mips, cpu, cpu-architecture

In college I've studied **x86** and **x64** architectures, among others that employ a **MOV** function. Having worked with them, it baffles me when I find one like the **MIPS r3000** one, or the Commodore 64 one, that do not have MOV and depend on saving to and loading from memory to move values between registers.

So, I was wondering, *what could be the reason behind this*? We've designed architectures based on signal processing and, at least in those cases, the implementation of a MOV function just relies on turning on a registry write and a registry read signal at the same time, thus rendering it a very simple command. Why, then, is it not implemented in these architectures? Are they so different, things don't work like this? Matters of space? Hipster design?

I can't help but wonder.

Comment: All these are ways to transfer memory. It doesn't matter what types of functions you have that move bytes.

Comment: The Commodore 64's CPU has MOV instructions, but with a different name: TAX, TXA, TAY, TYA, TSX, and TXS. Not all combinations are supported though, there's no TXY or TYX. The nature of the MIPS instruction set is that it has multiple instructions that can be used to move a value from one register to another. For example to move R1 to R2 you can do `or r2, r1, r1`, `or r2, r1, r0` `ori r2, r1, 0`, `add r2, r1, r0`, `addi r2, r1, 0`, etc...

Comment: Oh yes! You are right! Wow, I had not realised that!

Comment: Interesting that you point out how simple the internal implementation is for `mov`.  Using `or` to implement `mov` runs it through the ALU, potentially using more power unless you recognize that special-case.  But it saves opcode space to *not* have a dedicated `mov`.  (Also note that MIPS assembly language has a `mov` mnemonic, but it's a pseudo-instruction that assembles to one of those `add` or `or` instructions.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

X86 Needs a `MOV` instruction because its original incantation, the 8086, relies on 2 operand instructions. If your instruction set looks like:

```
instruction destination_op, source_op
```

There are few alternatives to a dedicated `mov` instruction.

If however like mips you have 3 operand instructions

```
instruction destination, source1, source2
```

Then there are many ways to move data from source to destination without needing a dedicated `mov` instruction.
Also some instruction set just have move instructions under a different name, e.g. `LD` (load) for the Z80 and `T??` (transfer) for the 6502.

Comment: Great answer, loved the Z80 and 6502 data as well. Thank you!